# How to decide on weights?

Tags: algorithm

For my work, I need some kind of algorithm with the following input and output:

Input: a set of dates (from the past). Output: a set of weights - one weight per one given date (the sum of all weights = 1).

The basic idea is that the closest date to today's date should receive the highest weight, the second closest date will get the second highest weight, and so on...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just "weight" them with their sorted order?  The weights wouldn't sum to 1, but you could easily fix that by dividing each value by the total.  Or, each weight could be the difference in days between the date and today.  Without knowing how the weight is being used, there's no right or wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These weights will be used in weighted average calculation.

Comment: Yes, but what "weighted average" do you want to compute?  For example, does something from 2 days ago count for 3 times as much as something from 6 days ago?  Or do the weights drop off by (1/2)^N?  This is something you need to know based on your particular situation.

Comment: What you're asking for is a monotonic function mapping a ranking (or distance) into a vector with an L1 norm of 1.  There are infinitely many such projections.  You should really think over the data more carefully, such as the weight assigned to something 24 hours ago, 7 days ago, 1 month, 1 year, etc.  This question needs to be revised.

Comment: @Iterator - you are right, I need to think a little bit more about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, for each date in your input set assign the amount of time between the date and today.

For example: the following date set `{today, tomorrow, yesterday, a week from today}` becomes `{0, 1, 1, 7}`. Formally: `val[i] = abs(today - date[i])`.

Second, inverse the values in such a way that their relative weights are reversed. The simplest way of doing so would be: `val[i] = 1/val[i]`.

Other suggestions:

- `val[i] = 1/val[i]^2`
- `val[i] = 1/sqrt(val[i])`
- `val[i] = 1/log(val[i])`

The hardest and most important part is deciding how to inverse the values. Think, what should be the nature of the weights? (do you want noticeable differences between two far away dates, or maybe two far away dates should have pretty equal weights? Do you want a date which is very close to today have an extremely bigger weight or a reasonably bigger weight?).

Note that you should come up with an inverting procedure where you cannot divide by zero. In the example above, dividing by `val[i]` results in division by zero. One method to avoid division by zero is called [smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing). The most trivial way to "smooth" your data is using the add-one smoothing where you just add one to each value (so today becomes 1, tomorrow becomes 2, next week becomes 8, etc).

Now the easiest part is to normalize the values so that they'll sum up to one.

```
sum = val[1] + val[2] + ... + val[n]
weight[i] = val[i]/sum for each i
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll go with the 1/val[i] inverse value, because I want noticeable differences between two far away dates and a date which is very close to today have an extremely bigger weight.

Comment: @Sash: The 1/val[i] will probably do. If you get crappy results, just play with the formula until you hack a better one. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

- Sort dates and remove dups
- Assign values (maybe starting from the farthest date in steps of 10 or whatever you need - these value can be arbitrary, they just reflect order and distance)
- Normalize weights to add up to 1

Executable pseudocode (tweakable):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random, pprint
from operator import itemgetter

# for simplicity's sake dates are integers here ...
pivot_date = 1000
past_dates = set(random.sample(range(1, pivot_date), 5))

weights, stepping = [], 10

for date in sorted(past_dates):
    weights.append( (date, stepping) )
    stepping += 10

sum_of_steppings = sum([ itemgetter(1)(x) for x in weights ])
normalized = [ (d, (w / float(sum_of_steppings)) ) for d, w in weights ]

pprint.pprint(normalized)

# Example output
# The 'date' closest to 1000 (here: 889) has the highest weight, 
# 703 the second highest, and so forth ...
# [(151, 0.06666666666666667),
#  (425, 0.13333333333333333),
#  (571, 0.2),
#  (703, 0.26666666666666666),
#  (889, 0.3333333333333333)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How to weight: just compute the difference of all dates and the current date

`x(i) = abs(date(i) - current_date)`

you can then use different expression to assign weights:

1. `w(i) = 1/x(i)`
2. `w(i) = exp(-x(i))`
3. `w(i) = exp(-x(i)^2))`
4. use gaussian distribution - more complicated, do not recommend

Then use normalized weights: `w(i)/sum(w(i))` so that the sum is 1.

(Note that the exponential func is always used by statisticians in survival analysis)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind to to use a geometric series:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

(1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+(1/16)+(1/32)+(1/64)+(1/128)+(1/256)..... sums to one.

Yesterday would be 1/2
2 days ago would be 1/4
and so on

Comment: this is in fact the same as point 2. in my answer, however with different exponent :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is is the index for the i-th date.
Assign weights equal to to Ni / D.
D0 is the first date.
Ni is the difference in days between the i-th date and the first date D0. 
D is the normalization factor

Answer (score 0):

converts dates to yyyymmddhhmiss format (24 hours), add all these values ​​and the total, divide by the total time, and sort by this value.

```
declare @data table
(
    Date bigint,
    Weight float
)
declare @sumTotal decimal(18,2)

insert into @Data (Date)
select top 100 
replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar,Datetime,20),'-',''),':',''),' ','')
from Dates

select @sumTotal=sum(Date)
from @Data

update @Data set
Weight=Date/@sumTotal

select * from @Data order by 2 desc
```